# How to get the native control in RadSideDrawer with nativescript angular2?

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a RadSideDrawer and I want to apply a directive to a Control that is in the MainContent of the RadSideDrawer.
Here is my Component using a RadSideDrawer.

```
<RadSideDrawer>
<StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
    <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout" backgroundGradient [gradientColors]="['red','blue']">
        <Image horizontalAlignment="center" class="avatar" src="res://avatar"></Image>
        <Label horizontalAlignment="center" class="name" text="Zeeko"></Label>
        <Label horizontalAlignment="center" class="email" text="1519560753@qq.com"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <Label [text]="'fa-file-text' | fonticon" class="fa icon"></Label>
            <Label class="side-item-lbl" text="我的简历"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <Label class="side-item-lbl" col="2" row="2" text="已投递"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)=openDrawer()></Button>
    <Label text="欢迎来到主页" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

And here is my directive.
[Directive](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24180363/)

Then I got unexpected ElementRef in the Directive's ngOnInit method, whoes `nativeElement` property is undefined.
If you can help me, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Posting pictures of code is not "recommended" and is simply silly lets not mention that it is also kind of a **** move to those trying to help because copy and paste is impossible. I see you are new so have that in mind for the future, there is way to embed code in your questions/answers using the markdown language (documentation here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov thank you for your suggestion, I've updated my question and I'll keep what you said in mind

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the RadSideDrawer sdk angular examples of the nativescript-telerik-ui plugin [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer).

More specifically you can get the `RadSideDrawerComponent` in the component code like so:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "tk-sidedrawer-getting-started",
    templateUrl: 'getting-started.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['getting-started.component.css']
})
export class SideDrawerGettingStartedComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: SideDrawerType;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
    }

    public openDrawer() {
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
    }
}
```

Copied from [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer/getting-started/getting-started.component.ts).

Comment: I mean I can get the drawer element, but can't get the element in the drawer

Comment: Rewrite you question then, there is no mention of any content of the side drawer. The RadSideDrawer instance has a **mainContent** and **drawerContent** properties which hold the declared content here is the API documentation (http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radsidedrawer.html).

Comment: I've updated my question could you please have a look ?